# I am making a project where User API call and fetch the data and display in recycler view

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

This is the code in which api is call and fetch the data and display in recyler view data and data1 are the deatils of api data but when I am launching the app it is showing blank screen. I want to make a network call using Retrofit, and fetch the list. (URL to fetch the user list https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2)
and then In a RecyclerView in the user list will be shown
Please help and tell what is wrong in the code.

User Adapter

```
  package com.example.userlisttest.Adapter

import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.userlisttest.Model.Data
import com.example.userlisttest.R
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.item_view.view.*

class UserAdapter(private val context: Context): RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {
    private val dataList = ArrayList<Data>()
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        var itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {

        return dataList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
//        holder.image = dataList.get(position)
        Picasso.get().load(dataList[position].avatar)
        val data = dataList[position]
        val userfullname = holder.itemView.full_name
        val image = holder.itemView.avatar
        val fullname = "$(data.firstname) $(data.lastname)"
        userfullname.text = (fullname as TextView).toString()
        Picasso.get().load(data.avatar).into(image)
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener() {
            Toast.makeText(context, fullname, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

    class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var image: ImageView? = null
        var text: TextView? = null

        init {
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.avatar)
            text = itemView.findViewById(R.id.full_name)


        }
    }
}

Retrofit
  
    package com.example.userlisttest.Retrofit.RetrofitClass

import com.example.userlisttest.Model.Data1
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory

object RetrofitClient{
    private val BASE_URL = "https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2"
    private var retrofit:Retrofit?=null
    fun getApiClient(baseUrl:String): Retrofit {
        val gson = GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create()
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build()
        }
        return retrofit!!
    }
}

Interface

      package com.example.userlisttest.Retrofit.RetrofitClass

import com.example.userlisttest.Model.Data
import com.example.userlisttest.Model.Data1
import retrofit2.http.GET

interface RetrofitService {
    @GET("users")
    fun getUserList(): List<Data>
    fun UserList(): List<Data1>

}

Data
   
   package com.example.userlisttest.Model

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

data class Data1 (
    @SerializedName("data")
    val data: List<Data>? = null,

    @SerializedName("page")
    val page:Int = 0,
    @SerializedName("perpage")
    val perpage:Int = 0,
    @SerializedName("total")
    val total:Int = 0,
    @SerializedName("totalpage")
    val totalPage:Int = 0
)

Data

   package com.example.userlisttest.Model

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

data class Data (
    @SerializedName("id")
    val id:Int,
     @SerializedName("email")
    val email:String,
    @SerializedName("firstname")
    val firstname : String,
    @SerializedName("lastname")
    val lastname: String,
    @SerializedName("avatar")
    val avatar: String,
)

MainActivity

      class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
       private val dataList = ArrayList<Data>()
//    private lateinit var adapter: UserAdapter
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second)

        val adapter = UserAdapter(this)
        val recyclerView: RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.userList)
//        adapter = UserAdapter(context)
        val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

you should call the users api and then pass the data to the adapter

Answer (score 0):

You are not making the request to fetch the data from the source (https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2).
You need to fetch the data using retrofit and pass it to the UserAdapter otherwise the arrayList used in the Adapter will be always empty.